# Cant delete folders with files in it:

Tags: files, directory, delete

When i try to delete folder with some files nomater how it don't allow me to delete it(when i right click the folder and click delete the option is active but does nothing), first i have to delete all files from the folder and then i can to delete it. How to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried deleting it as a super user? `sudo rm -rf <folder_name>`  **Make sure that you're deleting the right folder.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the directory where the folder is present from terminal

try this:

```
sudo rm -r foldername
```

this should delete the folder completely.

Comment: If the offending folder is somewhere inside your home folder, try first the above command without `sudo`. If that fails (improbable but you never know) then run it with `sudo`.